# Is it possible to call a stored procedure with multi-valued arguments?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

There's a stored procedure I'm studying. Would this be a possible call? -

```
exec [dbo].[prc_RPT_Respondent_Answer] '20121011', '20121017' , 18964 , "3", "30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,130"
```

I'm guessing the  `"30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,130"` argument is handled by code like the following(which is from the referenced sproc:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT 
    INTO #tempClientLK_ResponseStatuses
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, val) FROM dbo.Split(@ClientResponseRange, ',')  
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work. I already have used this approach, few times. 
If you are asking about how to write that table valued function dbo.Split() then you may check this link-

http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can with below url, it might be helps you to resolved your problem

[How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/sql-server-2008-how-to-split-a-comma-seperated-value-to-columns)